# Get the URL for digital experiences domain via APEX

Tags: apex, digital-experience

Is there a way to get the URL for the digital experiences domain from within APEX?

Page 19 of [Experience Cloud](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities.pdf) documentation shows how the Admin sets/gets this Domain.  But I need to retrieve it in my code so that I can generate a link to it in my LWC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @identigral for the link to similar previous question/answer...

```
SELECT Id FROM Site WHERE Name = 'XXX'

SELECT SecureUrl FROM SiteDetail WHERE DurableId = 'XXX'
```

(Obviously, replacing XXX with the Name of the site you want, and passing that Id to the second query.)

Uses two DML, which seems excessive, but does what I need it to do.

Comment: Hi, when there is an existing answer on another question, please don't create a new answer on a new question unless you are adding some new value. It is normal to simply have the duplicate question closed as a duplicate. I have voted thus.

Comment: I didn't consider it an exact duplicate, as their question was not regarding Digital Experiences.

Comment: A digital experience IS a site making this a duplicate in the eyes of this community :)